# Highlight bracket on editor

Tags: c#, java, vb.net

I've built a basic editor which have code auto-completion feature and also shows parameter list. Now I want to add **highlight matching bracket** feature. How to do this?

**Update**
I know some basic algorithm to find the matching bracket, but don't know how to highlight it! [to change the color or making it bold of the matching bracket].
 I'm using  multi-line textbox for this issue.

Comment: Starting at a left bracket, search one character at a time until you encounter a right bracket, if you encounter another left bracket search until you encounter 2 right brackets, etc...

Comment: @HunterMcMillen I've updated my question and made it more detailed. Please review. Thnx :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your current features you likely to have some sort of parsed tree of the source. If it is true you should be able to relatively easy to find node that represent braces above current location in the source.

Otherwise counting braces as Hunter McMillen suggested may be enough. Don't forget to skip comments and string literals if you support them.

Comment: I've updated my question and made it more detailed. Please review. Thnx :)

Comment: @Sourav, You probably should create new question instead as this one did not look like related to "highlighting", but rather "find matching bracket" part. BTW to my knowledge the answer is no, basic text box does not support distinct colors for characters - look into using RichTextBox instead.